# Any $5$ element subset of $\{1,\dots, 9\}$ contains an arithmetic progression.

Tags: combinatorics

How to show that any $5$ element subset of $X={1,2,3,...9}$ contains at least one arithmetic progression of length $3$.

Just a hint would do. Please don't post complete solution.

Comment: Have you tried Pigeon hole principle? I'm not sure how to apply it here myself, but it could be helpful.

Comment: Or maybe Ramsey Theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement can't be proven because it is false. Consider $$\{1,2,6,8,9\}$$

Comment: Thanks! I have been trying to do it for 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

A workable solution would be as follows: split the set up into odd and even elements. Consider the case where $4$ are even and $1$ is odd. This is easy. Then $3$ even and $2$ odd, etc. The number of cases that occur is small enough to treat them exhaustively.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a proof by contradiction? Suppose there exists a subset of 5 elements from $[9]$ that contain no arithmetic progression of length 3. So the maximal progression has length 2. What can you say about the elements of the set that has this property?